# Remove whitespace CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using css grid to layout my website. I have the general effect I want for a sticky side bar using

```
.page {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 250px auto;
        grid-column-gap: 3%;
    }
    .sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
      background: red;
    }
    .main {
      grid-column-start: 2;
      background: pink;
    }
```

Using markup as follows

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <p>sidebar</p>
    </div>

      <div class="main">
      </div>
    </div>
```

I know I can get rid of the column gap by using `grid-column-gap=0` but I can't get rid of the margin on the outside of the page div for some reason? I have tried using `margin=0` and `margin-left=0` but I cannot get the side bar all the way to the left without the white space. Does css grid require something different or is there something I am misunderstanding? Thanks!
[image: screenshot]

Comment: `body { margin: 0 }`

Comment: Oh my god, of course. That was so dumb, thank you!